# Do I need permission to use a company's logo for my website application?

Tags: legal, copyright, web-applications

I am creating a review website application where people can review particular companies, products or services according to the people's experience on various points like Support, Value, Up-time, etc.

Can I use these logos without asking permission from them?

Comment: The question you're asking should be posed to a lawyer, not random strangers on the internet. You'll have to look into the Copyright & Fair use laws in your jurisdiction.

Comment: Sorry but the question is too board and unlikely to help others due to the fact that terms of use and conditions of branding logo's varies from company to company. You already have a few good answers but you should always ask the company if unsure.

Comment: @SimonHayter: The question is generic - even though the two answers seem to assume a more specific approach - and the answer can also be generic. At least the trademark may be used freely in the US under the nominative use restrictions. Whether copyright on the logo poses additional limitations I don't know for sure, but at least under US law the IANAL conclusion seems to be that using the logos is fine.

Comment: The question can be made more generic by editing it, currently the question is open to different interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the company.

Some might be ok with you using the logo, some might not be ok, some might  even require you do follow certain rules.

For example Microsoft has very specific rules for using their logo: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/intellectualproperty/trademarks/usage/logo.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Pit's answer, also there's matter of copyrighted material. Most of the companies have registered name / trademark, so you need to ask them if they are willing to participate.